# Passing an id to a method via a post form in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following scenario:

A user is viewing a post on my application at the following url: `/posts/Post_tile-210`

and I want them to be able to create comments against this post. This will be done by creating a relationship between the comment and post using the post id as a foreign key in the comments table.

My question is that I see three possible ways to pass the post id to add comment method:

1.) Pass the post id via the form action like: `/comment/add/id:210`

2.) Pass the post id via a hidden field like: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="210">`

3.) Grab the post id in the controller method via the url itself

What is the best way and what are the pros and cons? I like the first the best as it seems nice and easy to setup and feels more consistent with query/named params in Cake Apps.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `post_id` in your Comment model and table, is easier to use hidden field:

```
echo $this->Form->input('post_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $post_id));
```

And when you submit this form you get a complete array ready for you to save the comment with the post foreing key.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it either way. You can post it as a hidden field:

```
echo $this->Form->input('post_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $post_id));
```

or as parameter on the submission:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Post', array('type' => 'post', 'url' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add', $post_id)));
```

Making the post_id a hidden field will give you the advantage of already including the post_id in the request without requiring any additional code to use it with the `$this->Model->save`, because it will be included as `$this->data['Comment']['post_id']`. This means that you will only need to call `$this->Comment->save($this->data);` and it will save it to the table.

If you pass it on the URL as a parameter, you will then need to set it so it will save in one of two ways:

```
$this->data['Comment']['post_id'] = $post_id;
```

or

```
$this->Comment->post_id = $post_id;
```

Therefore, the best practice would be to include it as a hidden field in the form.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up the controller method like:

```
 function add(post_id){
```

And pass it like

```
 URL/comment/add/variable
```